# Binding query param in LENGTH() condition doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having some trouble finding any info about this problem, but it appears to be a limitation of SQLite.

Consider a simple `words` table with 2 fields, `_id` (int) and `word` (text).  The following query works and returns the expected results (all words which are 12 characters or less):

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE LENGTH(word) <= 12;
```

However if this character limit needs to be dynamic and made into a parameter, the query no longer works. 
 It returns all rows of the table:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE LENGTH(word) <= ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[]{ Integer.toString(12) });
```

I also tried selecting the length as a new column, then applying the condition to that, but it gives the same results:

```
String query = "SELECT w.*, LENGTH(w.word) AS word_length FROM words w WHERE word_length <= ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[]{ Integer.toString(12) });
```

Is my only option to just filter through the query results afterward?  Why do parameterized conditions on normal INT columns work but not on LENGTH()? (e.g. `WHERE _id < ?` works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql statement that is executed with:

```
rawQuery(query, new String[]{ Integer.toString(12) });
```

is:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE LENGTH(word) <= '12';
```

and not:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE LENGTH(word) <= 12;
```

because `rawQuery()` treats all the passed parameters as strings and encloses all of them inside single quotes.
So the integer `LENGTH(word)` is compared to a string literal like `12` and this is where exists a feature of SQLite which states that:

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

(from [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)). 
So all integers are considered less than the string literal `'12'`.
Of course this is not what you want and expect, so what you can do is force a conversion of `'12'` to the integer `12` and you can do it by adding `0` to it:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE LENGTH(word) <= ? + 0";
```

What this does is an implicit conversion of `'12'` to `12` because you apply to it a numeric operation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - I think the main thing that was throwing me off was why an integer field like `_id <= '12'` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: No this does not have this problem. This *feature* of SQLite does not apply to column values and expressions like cast(length(word) as int) or sum(length(word)) because they all force the conversion to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I rubber duck this I'm able to figure out a workaround by casting the field to an integer:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE CAST(LENGTH(word) AS INTEGER) <= ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[]{ Integer.toString(12) });
```

Seems excessive but I guess the return value of LENGTH() isn't considered an integer (all documentation I've come across just says it "returns the number of characters")

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Integer.parseInt()` ? I think your query need's integer parameter and you are converting it to string :)